# NPM permission error installing modules for material design

Tags: npm, material-design, permission-denied

So, I really want to get started using material design. I'm using their getting started guide (https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/). Everything worked until the part where I have to install the modules. There I got the error:

gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/paul/Code/Material_Design_Test/Test4/node_modules/node-sass/build'

And then because of this the npm start command did not work either.

I've tried running it with sudo, same error. Tried to give me ownership of the folders, as sudo. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may run with sudo mode or else give the folder ownership with your user account and try to run it again

chown -R yourusername:yourusername directory

Comment: remove your node modules folder and reinstall them[ rm -fr node-modules/ and npm install]. ensure to give permission to your username so that you wont need root access to run the command